# Run custom script in SQL Server Express

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, sql-server-express, windows-task-scheduler, sql-scripts

I am trying to run a script on Task Scheduler to update a column in my database every 1 hour.

I have table `vw_invoices` and a column `ExportLock` with a default value of 0 which is "unlocked".

I want to run a query to update `ExportLock` to 1. Currently I am running

```
update Worldwide.dbo.vw_Invoices 
set ExportLocked = 1
```

Comment: Your question does not tell us what you need help with!?  Which part is not working for you?

Comment: I am trying to create a script with task schduler to run every hour in my SQL server database and update my vw_invoices from unlock to luck.
currently i update it manually by running script Worldwide.dbo.vw_Invoices set ExportLocked = 1
how can i create a task scheduler to do this for me ?

Comment: @TheGameIsWar has provided a nice answer below.  Have you had a chance to try that out yet?

Comment: yes I did the as he recommended
sqlcmd 
    -S <Sf-Frank>\<sql2012> 
    -i <c:\MyScript.sql> (inside MyScript.sql I have 'update Worldwide.dbo.vw_Invoices set ExportLocked = 1' )
Created textfile name myoutput created a task schedler to run this, but didn't work.

Comment: Try: `sqlcmd -S sf-Frank\sql2012 -i C:\MyScript.sql`.  You don't need the angle quotes.

Comment: For more on SQLCmd check out the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms162773.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

Answer (score 3):

Use SQLCMD along with windows task scheduler to mimic SQL Agent on SQL Server Express:

```
sqlcmd 
    -S <ComputerName>\<InstanceName> 
    -i <c:\MyScript.sql>
    -o <c:myutput.txt
```

Keep the above in a text file and save it as .BAT file and schedule through task scheduler

Answer (score -1):

[image]

I found what I was looking for and here is what I did worked great, I appreciate everyone's help

Comment: Please **[edit]** your post and show the actual code / command / script / input / output as text instead of screenshots. Others can't copy and paste from your images. [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/1402846) for details. Thank you.